# Attachment too large for mailing - should there have been a warning?

Tags: civimail, civireport, logging

Recently had a user attach a .docx file that was 14 MB to a mailing.  (Probably a single picture in the document was to blame.)  As one would expect, the messages bounced rather than being delivered.  However, the mailing reports just showed a bounce type of Syntax.  As you can imagine, this is rather unhelpful.  Digging around, I finally turned to the system's logging for maillog where I found the report of the attachment too large.  Should I have found this information somewhere in CiviCRM itself?  Perhaps in the mailing report that I overlooked?

Comment: Did you send a test e-mail to yourself first? Always a good idea. 14MB is pretty huge for an attachment - I believe Outlook/Exchange will often not allow receiving attachments larger than 10MB, for example. Also the fact that it's a .docx and could contain malware, like a Word macro, would probably cause many receiving systems to block it.

Comment: Yep.  Again, you are correct.  Those are all real problems that users are really good at not knowing, not remembering, and ignoring.

Comment: OK then for now my suggested real world solution is to require a test e-mail be sent via permissions :) . And I agree that there should be a warning that an attachment is (probably) too large, added in core.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an administrative setting that controls that limit here:

Administer -> System Settings -> Misc (Undelete, PDFs, Limits, Logging, Captcha, etc.)

The "syntax error" you are seeing is likely what the Civi mailer is getting back from the smtp server. I've seen that as a kind of catchall error message from mailers (e.g. it's what sparkpost will report when not configured). I don't think that Civi can do anything other than pass it on - i.e. the reporting error is from the system that's trying/failing to send out the mail.

Personally, I think there should be a message in the CiviMail system strongly discouraging attachments and encouraging attachments to be uploaded and linked to instead. That will increase deliverability.

The only really good use-case for attachments is if the document is private.

So the answer to your question is: "no".

Comment: While I agree with the sentiments, it's not real world, no matter how hard I fight it.  Additionally, while helpful in the overall theme, this doesn't answer the question.  Sorry.

Comment: Perhaps you want to submit an extension or PR with a warning or message when using attachments in a CiviMail? To the effect that it's a bad idea and it might fail with a misleading error message from the mailer?

Comment: Great idea, if it doesn't already exist.  However, this still is not on the topic of CiviCRM's bounce processing throwing an error/message when something like this happens.

Comment: But you did see the update to my answer that is specific to your question, yes?